# python googlemaps adding points

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

I'm using python to create a googlemaps with points marked in specific locations.

Adding point, I found, can be done using [pygmaps](http://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/). Now I need to add points and open a webpage for the map, find the points there:

```
import pygmaps
import webbrowser
mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.428, -122.145, 16)
mymap.setgrids(37.42, 37.43, 0.001, -122.15, -122.14, 0.001)
mymap.addpoint(37.427, -122.145, "#0000FF")
mymap.addradpoint(37.429, -122.145, 95, "#FF0000")
path = [(37.429, -122.145),(37.428, -122.145),(37.427, -122.145),(37.427, -122.146),(37.427, -122.146)]
mymap.addpath(path,"#00FF00")
mymap.draw('./mymap.draw.html')
url = 'http://maps.google.com'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

But my map did not appear. Can any one help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code and I believe I've found the problem. Right now, you're just opening the default Google Maps page, which knows nothing about the map you defined. Instead, change the next-to-last line to:

```
url = './mymap.draw.html'
```

and your map will appear in a new tab, exactly as specified. Have fun! :)

Comment: OHHHH I really appreciate that thankkkk u soooooooooooooooooo muchhh !! Danke Danke =)

Comment: @ingy No problem, thanks for the pointer to pygmaps. I'll have to play with that more sometime.

Answer (score 0):

```
mymap.draw('mymap.draw.html') 
url = 'mymap.draw.html'
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```